# But how to compute the following summation in r?

Tags: r

Give data

```
x<-c(80,80,75,62,62,62,62,62,58,58,58,58,58,58,50,50,50,50,50,56,70)
y<-c(42,37,37,28,18,18,19,20,15,14,14,13,11,12,8,7,8,8,9,15,15),
```

consider the linear regression with no intercept that `y_i=a*x_i+\epsilon`. I can compute the estimator by

```
      \hat{a}=lm(formula = y ~ x  +0)
```

which is 0.3057.

But how to compute the

1. `\sum_{i=1}^21 x_i*y_i`
2. `\sum_{i=1}^21 (y_i-a*x_i)^2`
3. `\sum_{i=1}^21 x_i^2`

in r.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? (1) is `sum(x * y)`... can you go from there?

Comment: following up on @GregorThomas's comment: all arithmetic operations in R are *vectorized*, so e.g. `x*y` does elementwise multiplication, `x^2` squares the terms of `x` elementwise, `a*x` where `a` is a scalar multiplies each element ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `a=lm(y~x+0)` outputs a list with lots of information, do `View(a)` to see it. If you want only the coefficient, do `a=lm(y~x+0)$coefficient`.

1. `sum(x*y)`
2. `sum(resid(lm(y~x+0))^2)` or `sum(lm(y~x+0)$residuals^2)` or `sum((y-a*x)^2)`
3. `sum(x^2)`